# Bulk copy CSV files using NPGSQL 3.0.5 BinaryImporter

Tags: npgsql

I have upgraded to NPGSQL 3.0.5 and realized the NpgsqlCopyIn is no more available. With older version I could process CSV file with NpgsqlCopyIn which is really fast and efficient for bulk copying huge data. I used

```
var copystr = "COPY tablename (col1,col2,etc) FROM 'csv file' STDIN WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER" ; 
NpgsqlCommand dbCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(copyStr, _DataStoreConnection); 
NpgsqlCopyIn copyIn = new NpgsqlCopyIn(dbCommand, _DataStoreConnection, stream); 
copyIn.Start();
```

But with 3.0 version, I couldn't find a way for bulk copying by just letting the binary importer that data is CSV. Instead I use the below code

```
StreamReader streamReader = null;
try {
    streamReader = new StreamReader(fileStream);
    {
        var copyStr = string.Format("COPY {0} ({1}) FROM STDIN (FORMAT BINARY)", _DataStoreName, string.Join(",", _DataStoreColumns.Select(a => a.ToLower())));
        if (_DataStoreConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        _DataStoreConnection.Open();
        string csvLine = string.Empty;
        while ((csvLine = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (lineCount > 0)
            {
                using (var importWriter = _DataStoreConnection.BeginBinaryImport(copyStr))
                {
                    importWriter.WriteRow(csvLine.Split(','));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lineCount++; //This is to skip the first line from the CSV file. First line will be header, so skip it.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way where I can specify the BinaryImporter that the input data is CSV, so that it takes care of delimiter and inserting the data to datastore as in NpgSqlCopyIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the binary importer to import CSV because, well, CSV isn't binary :)

The binary importer is a more efficient way to import your data, see an example in [the Npgsql docs](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html). If you absolutely have to import CSV, you can still do that via `BeginTextImport` but you have to format the text yourself, i.e. put the delimiter and so forth. See the docs for that as well.